# Hahn Banach and separation of points

Tags: functional-analysis

I understand why, given Hahn-Banach, for some nonzero $x\in X$ there exists a $f\in X'$ such that $||f||=1$ and $f(x)=||x||$. But why is it also so there exist $f\in X'$ such that if $f(x)=f(y)$ this implies that $x=y$? Because $||x||=||y||$ does not always imply $x=y$.

ps with $X'$ I mean the dual space of $X$, $X$ is obviously a normed linear space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Consider the point $z = x-y$. Then $z \neq 0$. Find an $f\in X'$ with $f(z) \neq 0$.

The norm of $x$ and $y$ is irrelevant, the norm of $x-y$ is what counts.

> But why is it also so there exist $f\in X′$ such that if $f(x)=f(y)$ this implies that $x=y$?

It isn't. The implication is that if you have $f(x) = f(y)$ for **all** $f\in X'$, then $x = y$.

(Note that that holds more generally for Hausdorff locally convex spaces, not only normed spaces.)

Comment: Yes thanks for the fast response.